# Is 'spaced out' appropriate in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I want to use a word/phrase to mean separated/distant in the context of time, Can I use  phrase 'spaced out' in this context?

> Surprise quizzes have been spaced out lately, just 2 in 5 weeks.

or

> My visits to this restaurant have been very spaced out.

Comment: I wouldn't use *spaced out* at all in these contexts. Metaphoric use of *[widely] spaced out* in the "temporal" (as opposed to "spatial") sense is credible, but usually it would probably be better to stick with more direct phrasing. Such as ***less common***, or ***infrequent***.

Comment: In particular, **spaced out** has the idiomatic meaning of being inattentive, absentminded, or otherwise "not in the here-and-how" mentally, and this sense could be read into both of your example sentence.

Comment: "[Sporadic](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sporadic)" might also suit your needs without the possible interpretation of visiting said restaurant in a daze, but I think saying it your way is OK as well.

Comment: *Spaced* all by itself means separated. You may say 'widely spaced' in these examples, or 'closely spaced' when you mean closer together in time, or 'spaced at X intervals' when you are being more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wouldn't use “spaced out” at all in these contexts. Metaphoric use of “[widely] spaced out” in the temporal (as opposed to spatial) sense is credible, but usually it would probably be better to stick with more direct phrasing. Such as **“less common”**, or **“infrequent”**. 
>   
> ([comment by FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/is-spaced-out-appropriate-in-this-context/11472#comment-19418))

> In particular, **“spaced out”** has the idiomatic meaning of being inattentive, absentminded, or otherwise not in the here-and-now mentally, and this sense could be read into both of your example sentences.
>   
> ([comment by chrylis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/is-spaced-out-appropriate-in-this-context/11472#comment-19429))

> **“Sporadic”** might also suit your needs without the possible interpretation of visiting said restaurant in a daze, but I think saying it your way is OK as well.
>   
> ([comment by Tyler James Young](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/is-spaced-out-appropriate-in-this-context/11472#comment-19430))

> “Spaced” all by itself means separated. You may say “widely spaced” in these examples, or “closely spaced” when you mean closer together in time, or “spaced at X intervals” when you are being more precise.
>   
> ([comment by StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/is-spaced-out-appropriate-in-this-context/11472#comment-19431))

Comment: I added attributions to the source links due to the ephemeral nature of comments.